# TypeScript array.map() with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of `Foo` called `fooArray`, but I would like to `map()` the array to only contain the “key: value” pairs which are defined in `arrayOfKeys`.

```js
class Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, age: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let fooArray: Foo[] = [
  new Foo(1, 'Foo', 20), 
  new Foo(2, 'Bar', 21),
  new Foo(3, 'MyFoo', 20)
  ];


//The keys I would like to select from Foo.
const arrayOfKeys: (keyof Foo)[] = ['name', 'age'];
```

I do not know what to do to get the desired result below:

```js
// The result is a copy of 'fooArray', but the objects only 
// contain the keys (and their values) defined in 'arrayOfKeys'.
[
   { name: 'Foo', age: 20 },
   { name: 'Bar', age: 21 },
   { name: 'MyFoo', age: 20 }
]
```

Comment: You probably want `array.filter` not `array.map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably do this by creating a new object in the map and returning it?

Something like

```
const fooArrayWithLimitedKeys = fooArray.map(item => arrayOfKeys.reduce(
  (accumulator, key) => {
    accumulator[key] = item[key]
    return accumulator
  }, {})
)
```

it can also be written without `reduce` like follows:

```
const fooArrayWithLimitedKeys = fooArray.map(item => {
  const returnValue = {}
  arrayOfKeys.forEach(key => {
    returnValue[key] = item[key]
  })
  return returnValue;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you simply want to modify each item of your array of objects to only contain desired keys, you may go like that:

```js
const src = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Foo', age: 20 },
   { id: 2, name: 'Bar', age: 21 },
   { id: 3, name: 'MyFoo', age: 20 }
]

const keys = ['name', 'age']

const result = src.map(item => Object.assign(
  ...keys.map(key => ({[key]: item[key]}))
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Works perfectly in JavaScript but sadly it doesn't work in TypeScript. Error: ```TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object Destructuring, inside a map function, something like that.

```
class Foo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, age: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let fooArray: Foo[] = [
  new Foo(1, 'Foo', 20), 
  new Foo(2, 'Bar', 21),
  new Foo(3, 'MyFoo', 20)
  ];
const arrayOfKeys: (keyof Foo)[] = ['name', 'age'];  

const result = fooArray.map(element =>(({name,age}) => ({name,age}))(element));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if you don't really need to reassign fooArray further in code I would recommend it be a const.

Then you can add something like pick function, if you don't want to use lodash or underscore:

```
function pick(object: any, keys: string[]) {
    return keys.map((key: string) => ({ [key]: object[key] }))
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const res = fooArray.map(el => pick(el, arrayOfKeys))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can create generic function which will accept target array and array of fields to be extracted. You should loop on desired fields and save them to result object. Heres solution in TypeScript:

**Generic function**

```
function mapToLimitedProps<A, Keys extends (keyof A)[]>(arr: A[], keys: Keys) {
    return arr.map(item => {
        let result: Partial<{
            [key in Keys[number]]: A[key]
        }> = {};

        keys.forEach(key => {
            result[key] = item[key];
        })

        return result;
    })
}
```

**Usage**

```js
mapToLimitedProps(fooArray, arrayOfKeys);
```